# Firebase - Email Verification Mail Not Working - An internal error has occurred. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send a verification email after successful registration of user. Which gives me the error `An internal error has occurred. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]`. This is the code I have at present -

```
public void signUpUser(View view){

    EditText mailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText pwdEditTet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    String email = mailEditText.getText().toString();
    String password = pwdEditTet.getText().toString();

    Log.d("Info",email);
    Log.d("Info",password);

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            try {
                AuthResult result = task.getResult();

                Log.d("Sign up", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Log.d("Sign up", "Sending verification email");
                    // Sending the verification email
                    //FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Log.d("Email Sent", "Verification Email sent.");
                                    }else{
                                        Log.d("Email Sent",task.getException().getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.user_exist,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Exception",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the log which is getting printed -

```
10-11 10:10:50.372 31518-31518/au.com.savedme D/Sign up: Sending verification email
10-11 10:10:51.438 31518-31518/au.com.savedme D/Email Sent: An internal error has occurred. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]
10-11 10:11:00.429 31518-31538/au.com.savedme W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Please have a look and let me know in case I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: After creating user, sign in that user. Use mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) before using mAuth.getCurrentUser().

Comment: Thank you for the response, however even after using `mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);` it isn't working.

Comment: @Dexter: creating a user automatically signs them in, so that shouldn't be the problem here.

Comment: Can you try using `task.getResult().getUser().sendEmailVerification(...`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes already tried that but did not work. I have also tried mAuth, and `task.getResult().getUser().sendEmailVerification(...` did not work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same issue, and the reason i found behind this is, if you are trying this code with same user which you have already created and then deleted it from firebase console, it will not work.

Try with new email address which you have not tried a single time, and it will work.

> Note that [createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) not only creates the user,
>   but also, if successful, signs the user in. When the creation and
>   sign-in occurs when there is an existing signed-in user, there appears
>   to be a Firebase bug related to signing out and clearing the cache for
>   the previous user.
>
> I was able to make your code work for a previously signed-in and later
>   deleted user by calling [signOut()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signOut()) before
>   `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060711/3134215)

Comment: Yes Ravi this is the correct answer , I found this out myself but forgot to add here. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. What I found out is that, mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification() is not working inside mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) method.
I wrote the code outside the createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) method and bang I received the verification email. Strange.

```
 FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(user!=null){
        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this,new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.i("Success","Yes");

                }
                else {
                    Log.i("Success","No"+task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for analysis, however shouldn't we send the verification mail inside create user method. Since it is only for new user. Did you also tried to call the outside method from create user method?

Comment: Yes, it should be called inside create user method. I applied the same logic as yours initially, called the sendEmailVerification() inside create user method. Getting the same error as yours.

Comment: I created a button to call sendEmailVerification(), still not working. I am not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have enabled Email/Password authentication in console? If not, you can go to https://console.firebase.google.com and click on your project, click 'Auth', then 'SIGN-IN METHOD', click on pen icon to enable it. Hope this helps!