# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase authentication with email and password, here is my code

```
mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User registered successfully " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                finish();
                                Log.e("RegisterActivity", "onComplete: " + task.getResult().toString());
                            } else
                                Log.e("RegisterActivity", "onComplete: " + task.getException().toString());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

After getting registered successfully i am sending confirmation mail to user, but getting this error.

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]
```

I have checked it in firebase also, my user is registered and it is available there, but somehow i am not able to send confirmation mail.

Comment: Sometime it takes some extra time to create a user in firebase so your user is probably not created when you are trying to send him a email.

Comment: but in toast i am getting `user.getEmail()`, if user is not created i should not get email address also.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you replace `user = task.getResult().getUser()` with `user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()`?

Comment: @qbix if i am using `mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` it is showing `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and ran your code with Firebase 9.6.1.  When I passed an email address to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` that had never been used before, `sendEmailVerification()` completed successfully.  I observed the failure you reported when I used an email address for a user that I had previously created and then deleted at the Firebase console.  Are you seeing the failure when you use addresses you have used before and then deleted?

Note that [createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) not only creates the user, but also, if successful, signs the user in.  When the creation and sign-in occurs when there is an existing signed-in user, there appears to be a Firebase bug related to signing out and clearing the cache for the previous user.

I was able to make your code work for a previously signed-in and later deleted user by calling [signOut()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signOut()) before `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AuthStateListener()` to see when a user is signed in that will ensure that user has successfully created and logged in then you can verify your user.

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in

             VerifyYourUserWithEmail(); 


            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is use of verification mail after user signin? It should be sent after registeration and then user should be allowed to login right?